# How to reduce minutes but add hours in php

Tags: time, timezone, date-arithmetic

How can I add hours as well as subtract minutes to get one result?

I can add 4 hours using the following code:

```
//Current Time
$hourMin = date('H:i:s');
echo "Current time is: ". $hourMin."<br>";

$hourDiff = date('H:i:s', time()+14400000);
echo "New time is: "    . $hourDiff;
```

I can subtract 7 minutes using the following code:

```
//Current Time
$hourMin = date('H:i:s');
echo "Current time is: ". $hourMin."<br>";

$hourDiff = date('H:i:s', time()-420000);
echo "New time is: "    . $hourDiff;
```

How do I do this so that my time in variable $hourDiff  is 4 hours ahead but 7 minutes behind?

Comment: So you need to add 3 hours and 53 minutes?

Comment: No, I want to:
1. Add 4 hours due to timezone difference
2. Subtract 7 minutes due to other reasons

Correcting 14399580 to 14400000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$now = date("H:i:s", time());
$newTime = strtotime("$now +4 hours -7 minutes");
```

or

```
$newTime = strtotime("$now +3 hours +53 minutes");

echo "New time is: "    . date("H:i:s", $newTime);
```

something like this?

Comment: if this helped you and is the correct answer please accept it :) (the check on the left of this answer)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. 

I wanted to add 4 hours for timezone so it stays 4 for me :P
I am subtracting 7 minutes because of function which will continuously check for inputs :)

Comment: I´m glad that I could help you.